What is the best appraoch to closing an extrusion in preparation for 3D Printing
I'm new to Fusion360 and in the process of designing a prototype case to be 3D Printed.
I've created the following air vent which will be merged to a base.  I've generate the component with 3 sides but am unable to close the 4th side.
I attempted to create a new sketch from the edege of the left side wall (open end) and draw lines top and bottom but can't seem to create a Profile in which I can Extrude.  Any ideas/direction would be appreciated.


How does this relate to 3D printing? Please see the Help Center question "What topics can I ask about here?"

I would like to have this 3D Printed once completed but yes this is more of Fusion 360/CAD question.  Any suggestions on a more appropriate Forum?  Note when I googled my question a majority of the suggested posts were from this forum and hence why I posted here.

I would suggest that you [edit] the question including the fact that this will be 3D printed. If there are any other issues with the question, one of the more experienced users or moderators can give some additional guidance. Honestly, I also have some difficulty seeing if this type of question is on-topic.

You have the back sketch, so pull the wall all the way forward and do that again to subtract (cut) the inner part from it and do an extra extrude to create the bak wall.

You could try creating a new sketch on the face of the open side and projecting (Create > Project/Include > Project) the edges you need to close the body. Then, you would simply extrude the projected profile.

Since the original sketch was simple, I recreated it on the inside dimension of the open end which allowed me to construct a profile which I could select and extrude to match the other 3 sides.
For a more complicated sketch/body I'm sure there is a better approach.  If you know of one please comment but I've resolved my issue.
Update: I followed Edson's approach of recreating the sketch from the plane with cutout, extruding the walls up and then applying the fillet to the body which was the key.  Prior I had only applied fillets to sketches and then extruding.  Made all the difference.
